# How to stop being obsessed with manuscripts status

Tags: publications, peer-review

I have two manuscripts with status under review (and a third with ``ready for decision" status). I can't stop refreshing the journals homepage especially the one in the decision status. I know there will be an email. But I feel I'm too much on refreshing. I do check every five minutes or less.

I do have a conference submission though where I'm not doing any refreshing. I know notifications will be out on a certain date.

I feel I'm too obsessed. How to stop doing this?

Comment: Boy, it used to be easier in the old days - you sent it off and got an envelope back some time later.

Comment: @JonCuster, yes, and you spent the 3-6 months fretting and stewing, I expect.

Comment: @Buffy - not really, except for Phys Rev Letters. We worked hard on the papers and had good collaborations. At worst we had some small things to clear up for the reviewers. Plus, out of sight out of mind.

Comment: This is a question about obsessive behavior, not about academia.

Comment: Do something else. Work on the next paper, paint your house, build a boat.

Answer (score 8):

Start on a new paper.

Fall in love.

See a therapist.

Take up a new hobby or sport.

Get a dog.

Talk to your mom/kids.

Re-read *Lord of the Rings*.

Design a new course.

Go for a walk/run/swim/ski.

Repeat as necessary.

Not joking here. You are probably just bored. Do something that makes you less bored.

Comment: Read Dune :), but seriously, a good answer.